# How to run multiple Python/Shell scripts from one script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have 4 python and shell scripts that I would like to run one after another from one python script.

So let's say:

```
import script1
import script2
import script3


python script1.py &
#do something here to check if script1 has been completed and move to script 2
python script2.py &
#do something here to check if script2 has been completed and move to script 3
python script3.py &
#do something here to check if script3 has been completed and move to script 4 which is a shell script.
```

Could someone help with this please? thanks in advance!

Comment: do they define a `main` func? do they have a `if __name == 'main':` clause?

Comment: no, those scripts don't have this clause.

Comment: So simply `import` should make them run (it really does just executes the script...)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class something like this?

Comment: Try and get in the habit of putting a shebang as the first line of your script so readers and the kernel know which interpreter you are writing for, then you won't have to keep typing `python script.py` all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.run(['python', 'script1.py'])
subprocess.run(['python', 'script2.py'])
subprocess.run(['python', 'script3.py'])
```

---

If you only want each script to run if the previous one was successful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.run('python script1.py && python script2.py && python script3.py', shell=True)
```

I am using `shell=True` here because I am relying on the shell to interpret the `&&` and only let the next process run if the previous one was successful.

---

If you want them all to run in parallel with each other, and in the background:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.run('python script1.py &', shell=True)
subprocess.run('python script2.py &', shell=True)
subprocess.run('python script3.py &', shell=True)
```

I am using `shell=True` here because I am relying on the shell to interpret the `&` to mean that I want the processes to run run in the background so that I can carry on doing something else while they run.

---

In general, I wouldn't use Python at all for this, I would write a `bash` script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

python script1.py
python script2.py
python script3.py
```

Also, in general, I would make the first line of a Python script a shebang like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print('I am a Python script with shebang')
```

then I would make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Now, instead of running it with:

```
python script.py
```

the kernel knows which interpreter to use so I don't have to tell it every time and I can simply run it with:

```
script.py
```

if the directory it is located in is on my PATH. Or, if it is not on my PATH, I'd need:

```
/path/to/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Usecase

If you want to add more scripts in future, suggest you create a run.py file that responsible to pass the argument(integer) to the shell file.

Let say you like to run n(4) qty of shell script or python script that accept **1** argument.

Create a file **run.python** with the code below.

Below code illustrate

- instanceQty = Amount of shell script to run
- os.getcwd() = path to your current file
- mockScript.sh = **shell script** that I put on same directory with **run.py**

To run shell script

```
# this is python file with name run.py
import subprocess,os
instanceQty = 4
for i in range(0, instanceQty):
    print(os.getcwd())
    subprocess.Popen(f"{os.getcwd()}/mockScript.sh {i}",shell=True,executable='/bin/bash')
```

To run python script

```
import subprocess,os,sys
instanceQty = 4
for i in range(0, instanceQty):
    print(os.getcwd())
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,f"{os.getcwd()}/mockScript.py",str(i)])
```

Run this file with

> python run.py

permission problem on MacOS

> sudo chmod ug+x mockScript.sh

> sudo chmod ug+x run.py

**All code tested on Python 3.8.1 and MacOs 12.0.1 environment.**